# How to trace and troubleshoot SOLR i/o failures (CREATE error)?

Tags: java, debugging, memory, solr

**Hi guys: I'm new to SOLR, and am trying to troubleshoot a deployment failure in a fairly sophisticated code-base.**

I have , of course, the immediate need to understand this error :

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error executing default implementation of CREATE

```
Error executing default implementation of CREATE

request: http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=tmp_xxxx_count_abc&instanceDir=/tmp/solr_indexes_re/viewbuilder_pckg100121/myDataDirectory/part-00000&wb=javabin&version=2
```

**Generally, though, I have a long-term goal for learning from this problem :**

1)  In general : how can I decide when an error is on the client, vs on the server, when debugging a SOLR application ?  Are there reliable, useful user-oriented logs which I should be looking into ?

2) What is the meaning of SOLR's complaint that it err'd while running the "default implementation" of "CREATE" ?  Should this trigger any immediate fears ?

3) Im starting to note that sometimes, when memory is low, SOLR write cod throws some odd error messages, like for example, that it could not obtain  locks. -- Are there some unwritten ground rules for running/debugging SOLR clients and interpretting error messages ?

EDIT MORE DETAILS ON THE STACK TRACE :

In the terminal, I see a serverside stack trace as well :

```
SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error executing default implementation of CREATE
at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleCreateAction(CoreAdminHandler.java:308)
at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestBody(CoreAdminHandler.java:114)
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.handleAdminRequest(SolrDispatchFilter.java:309)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:185)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/tmp/solr_indexes_repo/viewbuilder_pckg100121/xxxxxxxx_count_distinct/part-00000/conf/', cwd=/Users/jayunit100/Development/apache-solr-3.4.0/example
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:268)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openConfig(SolrResourceLoader.java:234)
    at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:141)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.<init>(SolrConfig.java:131)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:435)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleCreateAction(CoreAdminHandler.java:303)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear to me, you need a solrconfig.xml file in your classpath

Comment: yup.  thats the core error.  The strange thing is how its arising -- solr is being launched with the right classpath parameters.

Comment: It's probably not that strange, do you have a solrconfig.xml file in your classpath or `/Users/jayunit100/Development/apache-solr-3.4.0/example` directory?

Comment: hmm.. well... this particular program actually is supposed to copy those files over. but when i use a default schema.xml, for example, copied into that directory... it works.  maybe if i change the client to make sure and copy the config xml files over BEFORE data files SOLR will be able to deal with it.